# Android studio error

Tags: android

> IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate
>   com/squareup/okhttp/RequestBody which is an ancestor of project class
>   com/baasbox/android/net/OkClient$InputRequestBody. Error:Execution
>   failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody

Some web pages say its a configuration error, others a compile time error.

Building the project works! But when running it the project this error occurs

Comment: Did you follow a proper guide on how to add this library to your project? Click [here](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) to check out their official guide to installation

Comment: I am not using okhttp in my project. I am using baasbox which uses okhttp

Comment: Well it appears not to include the okhttp library properly. Try doing it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with instant run which worked once I disabled it.

Answer (score 0):

add  to your build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'
```

try click button in android studio,build-----clean project------make project